# Insert many matrices in a table

Tags: tables, matrices

In the fourth row of the table How can I align the elements of the first column with the second column as described in the image?
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english,12pt,oneside]{book}
%\documentclass[11pt,draft]{article}
%\usepackage{fullpage}
%\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, %right=1in]{geometry}
%\usepackage[margin=1in, paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=11in]{geometry}
%\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[left=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{refstyle}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{bm,amsmath}
%----------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{pifont}
%\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
%-----------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{violet}{rgb}{0.7,0.2,0.8}
\definecolor{bluevert}{rgb}{0,0.9,1}
\definecolor{trustcolor}{rgb}{0.71,0.14,0.07}
\definecolor{PinkTriton}{rgb}{.708 ,.055 ,.275}
\definecolor{RedTriton}{rgb}{.491 ,.097 ,.066} % couleur rouge du triton
\definecolor{OrangeTriton}{rgb}{.953 ,.502 ,.04}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
%===============================================================================
  \newcommand*{\rowvec}[1]{\left[ #1\right]}


\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\bm{#1}}
\newcommand{\mat}[1]{\bm{#1}}
\newcommand{\tran}{^{\mathstrut\scriptscriptstyle\top}} 
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
%--------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
  \hskip -\arraycolsep
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother
%--------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

\tabref{dif_irm_tep}).
\begin{table}[ht!]
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Step2. Apply numerically stable ASR filter}\\
  \hline
  2a. 2.b & Given $ A = \begin{bmatrix}[ccc|c] \theta^5/20 & \theta^4/8 & \theta^3/6 & \theta^3/3\\ \theta^4/8 & \theta^3/3 & \theta^2/2 & \theta^2/2\\ \theta^3/6 & \theta^2/2 & \theta & 1 \end{bmatrix} $,$ A|_{\theta = 2}\begin{bmatrix}[ccc|c] 1.6000 & 2.0000 & 1.3333 & 2.6667\\ 2.0000 & 2.6667 & 2.0000 & 2.0000\\ 1.3333 & 2.0000 & 2.0000 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.
  compute $ R = \begin{bmatrix}[ccc|c] −3.8788 & 2.0000 & −3.0476 & −3.3247\\ 0 & −0.2576 & −0.6954 & 0.8886\\ 0 & 0 & 0.0797 & 0.5179 \end{bmatrix} $ where $ Q = \begin{bmatrix} −0.5541 & 0.0773 & −0.4618 \\ 0.5795 & −0.2576 & −0.8113 \\ 0.5976 & −0.7171 & 0.3586 \end{bmatrix}$ \\ 
   \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Step3. computation of the derivation of the ASR filter (p=1)}\\  
  \hline
  3a. 3b. 3c. 3d, 3e. & Given $ A_{\theta}{'} = \begin{bmatrix}[ccc|c] \theta^4/4 & \theta^3/2 & \theta^2/2 & \theta^2\\ \theta^3/2 & \theta^2 & \theta & \theta\\ \theta^2/2 & \theta & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $. So $ A_{\theta}{'}|_{\theta = 2} = \begin{bmatrix}[ccc|c] 4 & 4 & 2 & 4\\ 4 & 4 & 2 & 2\\ 2 & 2 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $. compute $QA_{\theta}{'}$. Denote $X_1 = \begin{bmatrix} −5.9105 & −5.9105 & −2.9552 \\ 1.0045 & 1.0045 & 0.5022 \\ 0.2390 & 0.2390 & 0.1195 \end{bmatrix} $,$N_1 = \begin{bmatrix} −3.6017 \\ 2.4725 \\ 0.9562 \end{bmatrix}$. Find $X_1R{11}^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} 2.0469 & −7.8778 & −27.5511 \\ −0.3479 & 1.3388 & 4.6822 \\ −0.0828 & 0.3186 & 1.1143 \end{bmatrix}$. Split it into $L_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ −0.3479 & 0 & 0 \\ −0.0828 & 0.3186 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $D_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 2.0469 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1.3388 & 0 \\ −0.0828 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $U_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & −7.8778 & −27.5511 \\ 0 & 0 & 4.6822 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$  \\
\hline
 \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Accuracy of the computations: $\|(A^TA)_{\theta = 2}{'}-(R^TR)_{\theta = 2}{'}\|=2.17.10^{-14}$}\\  
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
\caption{Illustrative calculation for Example1}
\label{tab:dif_irm_tep}
\end{table}\newpage
```

Comment: Welcome! Please provide the code for the table in the form of a small document we can compile to reproduce the non-alignment problem you want help with. Better still, just include the row you need help with as the rest is really irrelevant.

Comment: You're trying to annoy your reader with such an layout? Welcome to TeX.SE. You should show what you have tried so far

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - Not annoy, just confuse...

Comment: @Mico: Both of which ;-)

Comment: Please note that your objective is anything but clear: You mention a "fourth row", but in my opinion that's the row that reads "Step 3. Computation of the derivatives..."; this is a row without matrices... Also, the expression "align the elements of the first column with the second column" is anything but clear. Please edit your posting to highlight more clearly what exactly it you're trying to achieve. Please also clarify what you have placed all the material in a tabular-like environment -- what are you trying to achieve?